# Determine the generator of finite group of matrices with respect to matrix multiplication and all its subgroup with its generator as follows

Tags: matrices, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with elements:
\begin{align*}
  \alpha_1
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix},
  \alpha_2
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\
   1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix},
  \alpha_3
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   -1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1
  \end{bmatrix},
  \alpha_4
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   -1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  \alpha_5
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1
  \end{bmatrix},
  \alpha_6
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix},
  \alpha_7
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1
  \end{bmatrix},
  \alpha_8
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\
   -1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
  \end{align*}
with respect to matrix multiplication.

1. Find the generator of $G$.
2. Find all subgroups of $G$ and its generator.

The identity element of $G$ is $\alpha_1$.
I found that $\alpha_2^2=\alpha_3, \alpha_2^3=\alpha_4, \alpha_2^4=\alpha_1$; that is, the order of $\alpha_2$ is $4$. Next, $\alpha_i^2 = \alpha_1$ for $i=5,6,7,8$, i.e., the order of $\alpha_i,i=5,6,7,8,$ are $2$. Next, I found $\alpha_2 \alpha_5 = \alpha_6, \alpha_2^2 \alpha_5=\alpha_7,$ and $\alpha_2^3 \alpha_5 = \alpha_8$.
Hence, I found that the generator of $G$ is $\{\alpha_2, \alpha_5\}$, i.e., $G=\langle \alpha_2, \alpha_5 \rangle$.

Now, for 2, I found that the only subgroups of $G$ are
$$M_1=\{\alpha_1\},M_2=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_4\}, M_3=
\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4\},G.$$
Thus, $M_1=\langle \alpha_1 \rangle, M_2=\langle \alpha_2,\alpha_3 \rangle, M_3=\langle \alpha_2 \rangle,$ and $G=\langle \alpha_2, \alpha_5 \rangle$.

Am I true? If no, how to handle them correctly? Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What do you know about groups of order $8$? It might be best to exploit an isomorphism.

Comment: You're right about the generators. Your answer to the second part is wrong. --- Since $$\alpha_5\alpha_2\alpha_5^{-1}=\alpha_2^{-1},$$ the group must be isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order eight. You can then read off the subgroups from databases such as [Group Names](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/D4.html). We have the group given by the presentation $$D_4\cong\langle \alpha_2,\alpha_5\mid \alpha_2^4, \alpha_5^2, \alpha_5\alpha_2\alpha_5^{-1}=\alpha_2^{-1}\rangle.$$

Comment: This group of order 8 can't have a subgroup of order 3.

Comment: @EthanBolker So, what's the correct answer for 2?

Comment: You've found subgroups of order 1 and 4 (and 8). The only other possibility is order 2. Try squaring the various group elements. That should find those and hint at others of order 4.